# Having trouble making else/if statements run in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm very new to Python and am trying to teach myself a few things using various online resources.  In the WIkipedia article on algorithms, there is a sample BASIC program; I've decided to try and write the same program using Python, but I am running into problems with the syntax of my if/else statements.  I'm pretty sure it's a basic formatting problem, but I don't have enough experience with coding to understand what I'm doing wrong.  The following chunk of code:

```
# Euclid's algorithm for greatest common divisor

print "Euclid's algorithm for greatest common divisor"

print "Type two integers greater than 0"
("\n")
("\a")

# Gather input from user in the form of a string. 

("\n")
a = raw_input("Integer 1? ")
("\n")
b = raw_input("Integer 2? ")
("\n")

# Calculate equalities.

if b = 0:
    print a

elif a > b:
a = a - b
print a

b = b - a

if b = 0:
print a
```

returns the error:

```
  File "euclid.py", line 35
    if b = 0:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I realize the module as a whole is incomplete, but I would like to try to figure out what I'm doing wrong in this part before I move on to the next part.

Comment: What is in **line 35** ?

Comment: `==` is used for comparison, `=` is the assignment operator.

Comment: You seem to be missing some indentation.

Comment: What's with all the `("\n")` expressions? They don't do anything. If you're trying to print a newline, just use a plain `print` statement, all by itself.

Answer (score 4):

Two issues:

```
if b = 0: # this is assignment; you want == which is comparison
    print a

elif a > b:
a = a - b # this needs to be indented just like the print under the if clause
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using assignment where you wanted to test for equality. Use *two* `=` signs:

```
if b == 0:
```

`b = 0` is an assignment statement, and you cannot use statements inside of other statements; `b == 0` tests if `b` is equal to 0.

Answer (score 2):

1. = is assignment (as in `x=4`, which means `set x=4`).  == is equality checking.  You want ==.
2. python requires indentation.

Thus

```
if True:
print 'happy'`
```

is a syntax error, whereas

```
if True:
  print 'happy'
```

is okay.

1. This isn't strictly speaking a syntax error, but what are the `("\n")` statements in your code there for?  Currently they don't do anything.

Comment: Oh, yeah, the ("\n") statements are sort of there by accident.  One of the first things I did when I started learning this stuff is create a couple of simple scripts that formatted web pages, and I needed those statements in the code so that HTML didn't end up all smooshed together on one line.  Got into the habit of putting them in; forgot that I didn't need them for this particular script.  My bad.

Answer (score 0):

For most programming languages checks for equality are denoted by a double equal sign meaning check if these are equal and return true/1 or false/0. This is because you need to distinguish between asking if two things are equal and stating the relation.

So use == instead of =

Comment: OK, so I've done that, and that part seems to work - thanks for the input from everyone.  But now I seem to have another issue - at line 23 I get an error:  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'.  (Told you I was new at this :))